# Why is codecov with lcov not working correctly on Travis but on my local Linux Mint?

Tags: c++, gcov, lcov, codecov

I tried to add [Codecov](https://codecov.io/) to my CI build system for my [library](https://github.com/AMS21/Andres-Standard-Library).
The [travis script](https://github.com/AMS21/Andres-Standard-Library/blob/master/.travis.yml) looks like this:

```
lcov --directory . --capture --output-file coverage.info --gcov-tool gcov-8 # capture coverage info
lcov --remove coverage.info '/usr/*' --output-file coverage.info # filter out system
lcov --list coverage.info # debug info
# Uploading report to CodeCov
bash <(curl -s https://codecov.io/bash) || echo "Codecov did not collect coverage reports"
```

When I run these commands on my local Linux Mint machine everything works as expected. But on Travis it doesn't. [Report](https://travis-ci.org/AMS21/Andres-Standard-Library/jobs/406574331#L1145) looks like this:

```
Capturing coverage data from .
Found gcov version: 8.1.0
Scanning . for .gcda files ...
geninfo: WARNING: /home/travis/build/AMS21/Andres-Standard-Library/CMakeFiles/unittest.dir/test/src/cstddef/offsetof_test.cpp.gcno: Overlong record at end of file!
Found 132 data files in .
Processing unittest.dir/test/src/cstddef/offsetof_test.cpp.gcda
geninfo: WARNING: cannot find an entry for #home#travis#build#AMS21#Andres-Standard-Library#test#include#doctest.h.gcov in .gcno file, skipping file!
geninfo: WARNING: cannot find an entry for #home#travis#build#AMS21#Andres-Standard-Library#test#src#cstddef#offsetof_test.cpp.gcov in .gcno file, skipping file!
(...)
Finished .info-file creation
lcov: ERROR: no valid records found in tracefile coverage.info
Reading tracefile coverage.info
Reading tracefile coverage.info
lcov: ERROR: no valid records found in tracefile coverage.info
```

So obviously there is a Problem here, but I do not understand what it is. And I cant replicate it on my local machine and searching online I also couldn't find a solution.
Both travis and my local machine use gcov 8.1.0. And on travis I use lcov 1.13 and on my local machine version 1.12. I compile with the following [flags](https://travis-ci.org/AMS21/Andres-Standard-Library/jobs/406574331#L971):

```
-Wall (... various warning flags) -m32 -g -O0 -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage --coverage
```

I would be very thankful for any solutions or ideas.

Edit:
Fixed the problem. It seems that gcc 8 is causing some problems. Using gcc 7 works just fine.

Comment: Did you finally found a solution? I have the same problem here, I think it's an issue with the latest gcc/gcov, whiche version are you using on your machine and on travis?

Comment: "Both travis and my local machine use gcov 8.1.0. And on travis I use lcov 1.13 and on my local machine version 1.12." and "Edit: Fixed the problem. It seems that gcc 8 is causing some problems. Using gcc 7 works just fine."

Comment: As I said in my answer, there was a bug fix in 1.13-4, so you can try again with gcc8 and the latest LCOV

Answer (score 5):

I encountered a similar issue, I solved it by updating LCOV to the 1.13-4 version (on ubuntu 18.04 LTS, the version available with apt is 1.13-3)

Comment: I can confirm that this solves the problem on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I downloaded the .deb package from 18.10. It install just fine.